# need help implementing Spring MVC

Tags: java, spring, jsp, spring-mvc

I'm trying to implement Spring in my project.
i'm encountering a problem with `@RequestMapping`.

here is the location of my jsp files. I'm getting error 404.

[image]

here is the code in my spring-dispatcher-servlet.xml

```
<bean id="viewResolver"
    class="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.InternalResourceViewResolver">
    <property name="prefix">
        <value>/jsp/</value>
    </property>
    <property name="suffix">
        <value>.jsp</value>
    </property>
</bean>
```

and here is my web.xml

```
  <servlet>
    <servlet-name>spring-dispatcher</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>
        org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet
    </servlet-class>
  </servlet>
  <servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>spring-dispatcher</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/</url-pattern>
  </servlet-mapping>
```

here is the form,

```
            <form id="login-form" action="/cpanel" method="post">
                <div class="modal-body text-center">
                    <span id="error-message">${errorMessage}</span> <input
                        id="username" name="username" class="form-control" type="text"
                        placeholder="Username" required> <input name="password"
                        class="form-control" type="password" placeholder="Password"
                        required>
                </div>
                <div class="modal-footer">
                    <div>
                        <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary btn-lg btn-block">Login</button>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </form>
```

here is the controller class,

```
    @RequestMapping(value="/cpanel", method= RequestMethod.POST)
    public ModelAndView controlpanel(@RequestParam("username") String username, @RequestParam("password") String password, HttpSession session)
{
        ModelAndView mv = new ModelAndView("test");

        return mv;
    }
```

Comment: You're getting a 404 when doing what?

Comment: Can you show the URL you sent to `controlpanel`

Comment: Have you noticed you are mapping a POST request? if you visit `http://localhost:port/cpanel` it will throw a 404. You need to make a POST request, or change the mapping to a GET request (and provide the `username` and `password` params of course).

Comment: i used POST method in my form <form id="login-form" action="/cpanel" method="post">

Comment: So, the 404 happens after you click on the form submit button, right? Do you have a `test.jsp` file under `web/jsp`? Is your application deployed as the root application? Because if it isn't the action should be `"cpanel"`, or `"${pageContext.request.contextPath}/cpanel"`, but not `"/cpanel"`

Comment: yes. i do i have test.jsp inside web/jsp.

Comment: See my followup question in my previous comment.

Comment: sorry for the late reply, i'll try that.

Answer (score 0):

Your JSP files should be  in WEB-INF/JSP/ as per the configuration 
you have given

```
<bean id="viewResolver"
class="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.InternalResourceViewResolver">
<property name="prefix">
    <value>/jsp/</value>
</property>
<property name="suffix">
    <value>.jsp</value>
</property>
```